# python multi daemon in one program doesn't work

Tags: python, server, daemon

I try to build a python program that run two or more daemon in same time, the daemons all listen different port and do things according their code. But when I finish and run, I found that only one daemon can work but the second. How can I make that work? Following is my test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sys
import time
import socket
import logging
import atexit
import os
from signal import SIGTERM


class Daemon:
    """
    A generic daemon class.

    Usage: subclass the Daemon class and override the run() method
    """
    def __init__(self, pidfile, stdin='/dev/null', stdout='/dev/null', stderr='/dev/null'):
        self.stdin = stdin
        self.stdout = stdout
        self.stderr = stderr
        self.pidfile = pidfile

    def daemonize(self):
        """
        do the UNIX double-fork magic, see Stevens' "Advanced
        Programming in the UNIX Environment" for details (ISBN 0201563177)
        http://www.erlenstar.demon.co.uk/unix/faq_2.html#SEC16
        """
        try:
            pid = os.fork()
            if pid > 0:
                # exit first parent
                sys.exit(0)
        except OSError, e:
            sys.stderr.write("fork #1 failed: %d (%s)\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror))
            sys.exit(1)

        # decouple from parent environment
        os.chdir("/")
        os.setsid()
        os.umask(0)

        # do second fork
        try:
            pid = os.fork()
            if pid > 0:
                # exit from second parent
                sys.exit(0)
        except OSError, e:
            sys.stderr.write("fork #2 failed: %d (%s)\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror))
            sys.exit(1)

        # redirect standard file descriptors
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stderr.flush()
        si = file(self.stdin, 'r')
        so = file(self.stdout, 'a+')
        se = file(self.stderr, 'a+', 0)
        os.dup2(si.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())
        os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
        os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())

        # write pidfile
        atexit.register(self.delpid)
        pid = str(os.getpid())
        file(self.pidfile, 'w+').write("%s\n" % pid)

    def delpid(self):
        os.remove(self.pidfile)

    def start(self):
        """
        Start the daemon
        """
        # Check for a pidfile to see if the daemon already runs
        try:
            pf = file(self.pidfile, 'r')
            pid = int(pf.read().strip())
            pf.close()
        except IOError:
            pid = None

        if pid:
            message = "pidfile %s already exist. Daemon already running?\n"
            sys.stderr.write(message % self.pidfile)
            sys.exit(1)

        # Start the daemon
        self.daemonize()
        self.run()

    def stop(self):
        """
        Stop the daemon
        """
        # Get the pid from the pidfile
        try:
            pf = file(self.pidfile, 'r')
            pid = int(pf.read().strip())
            pf.close()
        except IOError:
            pid = None

        if not pid:
            message = "pidfile %s does not exist. Daemon not running?\n"
            sys.stderr.write(message % self.pidfile)
            return  # not an error in a restart

        # Try killing the daemon process
        try:
            while 1:
                os.kill(pid, SIGTERM)
                time.sleep(0.1)
        except OSError, err:
            err = str(err)
            if err.find("No such process") > 0:
                if os.path.exists(self.pidfile):
                    os.remove(self.pidfile)
            else:
                print str(err)
                sys.exit(1)

    def restart(self):
        """
        Restart the daemon
        """
        self.stop()
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        """
        You should override this method when you subclass Daemon. It will be called after the process has been
        daemonized by start() or restart().
        """


class controlDaemon(Daemon):
    global tcpListenPort
    global bufferSize

    def run(self):
        logger.debug("start listen:"+str(tcpListenPort))
        address = ('127.0.0.1', tcpListenPort)
        udpListenSocket2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        udpListenSocket2.bind(address)
        while True:
            data = udpListenSocket2.recv(bufferSize)
            logger.debug("received:{0}".format(data))
        udpListenSocket2.close()


class notificationPushDaemon(Daemon):
    global udpListenPort
    global bufferSize

    def run(self):
        logger.debug("start listen:"+str(udpListenPort))
        address = ('127.0.0.1', udpListenPort)
        udpListenSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        udpListenSocket.bind(address)
        while True:
            data = udpListenSocket.recv(bufferSize)
            logger.debug("received:{0}".format(data))
        udpListenSocket.close()


def InitLog():
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    fh = logging.FileHandler("tt.log")
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.addHandler(ch)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = logging.getLogger("logtest")
    InitLog()
    tcpListenPort = 19999
    udpListenPort = 19966
    tcpPidFile = '/tmp/test1.pid'
    udpPidFile = '/tmp/test2.pid'
    cDaemon = controlDaemon(tcpPidFile)
    npDaemon = notificationPushDaemon(udpPidFile)
    bufferSize = 65535

    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
            cDaemon.start()
            npDaemon.start()
        elif 'stop' == sys.argv[1]:
            cDaemon.stop()
            npDaemon.stop()
        elif 'restart' == sys.argv[1]:
            cDaemon.restart()
            npDaemon.restart()
        else:
            print "Unknown command"
            sys.exit(2)
            sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print "usage: %s start|stop|restart" % sys.argv[0]
        sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: You could use the multiprocessing library

Comment: Can you show me sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Unix daemon is a process so trying to have one process to be two deamons doesn't work.  Either write two separate daemons and another program or script to start/stop/restart both or write just one deamon and let it do two jobs in parallel with `threading` or `multiprocessing`.  Here is your example rewritten to use threads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8
import atexit
import logging
import os
import socket
import sys
import time
from contextlib import closing
from signal import SIGTERM
from threading import Thread

LOGGER = logging.getLogger('logtest')
PID_FILENAME = '/tmp/test.pid'
TCP_LISTEN_PORT = 19999
UDP_LISTEN_PORT = 19966
BUFFER_SIZE = 65535


class Daemon(object):
    pass
    # ... Class definition from question goes here ...


def control():
    LOGGER.debug('start listen: %s', TCP_LISTEN_PORT)
    address = ('127.0.0.1', TCP_LISTEN_PORT)
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_socket.bind(address)
    while True:
        sock, address = server_socket.accept()
        with closing(sock):
            while True:
                data = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                if not data:
                    break
                LOGGER.debug('received from %s: %s', address, data)


def push_notifications():
    LOGGER.debug('start listen: %s', UDP_LISTEN_PORT)
    address = ('127.0.0.1', UDP_LISTEN_PORT)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(address)
    while True:
        data, address = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
        LOGGER.debug('received from %s: %s', address, data)
    sock.close()


class TheDaemon(Daemon):

    @staticmethod
    def run():
        thread = Thread(target=control)
        thread.start()
        push_notifications()


def init_logging():
    LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('tt.log')
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
    )
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    LOGGER.addHandler(file_handler)
    LOGGER.addHandler(stream_handler)


def main():
    init_logging()
    commands = ['start', 'stop', 'restart']
    daemon = TheDaemon(PID_FILENAME)

    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        command = sys.argv[1]
        if command in commands:
            getattr(daemon, command)()
        else:
            print 'Unknown command'
            sys.exit(2)
    else:
        print 'usage: {0} {1}'.format(sys.argv[0], '|'.join(commands))
        sys.exit(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The TCP and UDP handling code had some errors.  If you expect many TCP connections at the same time you might want to handle single connections in their own threads.

The `global` statements did not have any effect.

Comment: WoW, your information is helpful. It's works!  The first time I had comment error that because I forgot to copy the code of daemon.   Thank you very much!

Comment: But I still have a question, why control start use thread.start(), but push_notifications just use function push_notifications()? What's the different? Is there all of them use thread for start is better?

Comment: You need to run two functions at the same time. As there is already a main thread you need just one *additional* thread. If you start a thread for each function there is still the main thread which has to do something so the program won't end.

Comment: But I tried to modify code "push_notifications()" to "t2 = Thread(target=push_notifications)" and "t2.start()", I found that the main program and the threads ended after I run "program.py stop". It seems that two threads can run and stop together.

Comment: The main thread doesn't end, it just sits there and waits for the other two to end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multiprocessing module of standard python.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Daemon(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        mp.Process.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        here everything that should be a demon goes


main():
daemon = Daemon()
daemon.daemon = True  # this lets the daemon be presistent in the memory, even when the program quits
daemon.start()
```

Comment: I try to modify my code, but nothing happen after running use "python md.py start"

Comment: That `Daemon` isn't a daemon in the Unix sense of the word, so this is no solution.